# Losing internet connection after shutting down

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, ethernet

I am experiencing a very peculiar issue lately with my home network.

The issue is the following: When casually working and doing stuff my internet connection is flawless. No interruptions or disruptions or anything. No drops on my speed etc.

The status of my modem is the following:

```
+---------------+
| Power     [√] |
| DSL       [√] |
| Online    [√] |
| Telephony [√] |
+---------------+
\________________\
```

BUT, the moment I shut down my laptop (running an Ubuntu 20.04 distro) the network connection gets scrambled. I have to power off and then power on the modem in order to restore it.

The modem indicators are now:

```
+---------------+
| Power     [√] |
| DSL       [√] |
| Online    [x] |
| Telephony [x] |
+---------------+
\________________\
```

It is a very peculiar issue that I have never encountered before. My machine, the laptop, is the only device connected via an Ethernet cable that goes on a Thunderbolt hub that I connect to it.

My ISP offered me a modem change that, as expected, did not solve my problem.

Obviously I have zero to none means to debug such an issue. I do suspect that it may be an issue of the Thunderbolt dock on which the Ethernet cable is connected solely because it started happening almost immediately after I started using it.

But this makes no sense to me. How could it be that the hub may be responsible for disrupting the whole network on such scenario?

Does anyone have any hints towards the solution of this issue?

Comment: Your router should have an ethernet admin interface where you can log in. Chances are, you can find some logs in the "Advanced" section of settings. Also, maybe even just poking around in there while it's in this error state (if you can log in then) might reveal something telling. Any error message you manage to come accross, you can put into a web search.

Comment: Your router diagram is not quite clear. Does your router have 1 WAN port, and 4 LAN ports? Does your DSL modem plug into the WAN port? Then you have laptop->thunderbolt_hub->router_LAN_port, correct? What make/model thunderbolt hub?

Comment: The picture shows a similar one to what I have, It is not a router it is the modem and if you want more then one connection you add a router or switch to it.

Comment: @David Yes. Please do excuse me.

Comment: @heynema I will edit the post. I am not talking about a router but about a modem device. The hub I got is called ```Lenovo USB-C Travel Hub```

Comment: Are you able to connect the laptop directly to the modem, without the hub?  Just to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Ray That's what I will be doing today. It is my only idea as well. I am going to work while having the laptop directly connected to the ethernet cable. I will update the post if something changes.

Comment: See https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds543919-lenovo-usb-c-travel-hub-firmware-tool-for-windows-7-10-32-bit-64-bit for a hub firmware update tool. Have your hub serial # handy.

Comment: Hello again everyone. I do confirm that the issue did not occur when my machine was directly connected via the same ethernet cable I was using on the hub. The network connection was not disrupted. So...that weirdly leaves my hub as a prime suspect. Following @heynnema 's advice I will proceed to update the firmware of the hub. What a weird situation...